# C++ Texture not displaying correctly: Merging into 1 colour

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, vbo, vao

I'm attempting to texture a VBO/VAO model cube. The cube is definitely rendering/drawn correctly, and as far as I know I am doing everything needed to load the texture.

However when it comes to applying the texture it appears to take an average of all colours in the texture, then apply that average to the entire cube. This results in it appearing to be "painted" with a plain, regular colour as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

this is the texture;

[image]

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening. Below is the code from my init, loadTexture and display functions (I did not write the loadTexture function):

***Init Function***
*(Only showing the code relevant to the cube + texture)*
    void init(void) {
        .
        .
        .
        pyramidTexture = TextureLoader::fiLoadTexture(wstring(L"Common\Resources\Textures\Sandstone.png"));

```
// Setup VAO for pyramid object
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &pyramidVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(pyramidVAO);

// Setup VBO for vertex position data
    glGenBuffers(1, &pyramidVertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidVertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pyramidVertices), pyramidVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0); // attribute 0 gets data from bound VBO (so assign vertex position buffer to attribute 0)

// Setup VBO for vertex colour data
    glGenBuffers(1, &pyramidColourBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidColourBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pyramidColours), pyramidColours, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0); // attribute 1 gets colour data

    glGenBuffers(3, &pyramidTexCoordBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidTexCoordBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pyramidTexCoordArray), pyramidTexCoordArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0);

// Enable vertex position and colour + Texture attribute arrays
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);

// Setup VBO for face index array
    glGenBuffers(1, &pyramidIndexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidIndexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pyramidVertexIndices), pyramidVertexIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(0);


    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE); // If we scale objects, ensure normal vectors are re-normalised to length 1.0 to keep lighting calculations correct (see lecture notes)
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST); // Best colour interpolation results
    .
    .
    .
}
```

***LoadTexture Function***

```
GLuint TextureLoader::fiLoadTexture(const wstring& textureFilePath) {

    BOOL                fiOkay = FALSE;
    GLuint              newTexture = 0;
    fipImage            I;

// Convert wstring to const char*
    wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> stringConverter;

    string S = stringConverter.to_bytes(textureFilePath);
    const char *filename = S.c_str();


// Call FreeImage to load the image file
    fiOkay = I.load(filename);

    if (!fiOkay) {

            cout << "FreeImagePlus: Cannot open image file.\n";
            return 0;
    }

    fiOkay = I.flipVertical();
    fiOkay = I.convertTo24Bits();

    if (!fiOkay) {

            cout << "FreeImagePlus: Conversion to 24 bits successful.\n";
            return 0;
    }

    auto w = I.getWidth();
    auto h = I.getHeight();

    BYTE *buffer = I.accessPixels();

    if (!buffer) {

             cout << "FreeImagePlus: Cannot access bitmap data.\n";
             return 0;
    }


    glGenTextures(1, &newTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, newTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

    // Setup default texture properties
    if (newTexture) {

            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    }

    return newTexture;
}
```

***Display Function***

```
void display(void) {

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set viewport to the client area of the current window
    glViewport(0, 0, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH), glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT));

    // Get view-projection transform as a GUMatrix4
    GUMatrix4 T = mainCamera->projectionTransform() * mainCamera->viewTransform();

    if (principleAxes)
        principleAxes->render(T);

    if (texturedQuad)
            texturedQuad->render(T * GUMatrix4::translationMatrix(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f));


// Fixed function rendering (Compatability profile only) - use this since CGImport is written against OpenGL 2.1
    glUseProgram(0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMultMatrixf((const float*)mainCamera->projectionTransform().M);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMultMatrixf((const float*)mainCamera->viewTransform().M);
    glMultMatrixf((const float*)GUMatrix4::translationMatrix(0.0f, -0.15f, 0.0f).M);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);

    if (exampleModel)
        exampleModel->renderTexturedModel();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    //Define position and direction (so appear at fixed point in scene)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, lightDirection);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);

    // enable texturing
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);


    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
//
// Pyramid VBO rendering
//

    // Use basic shader for rendering pyramid (we'll look at this in more detail next week)
    glUseProgram(basicShader);

    static GLint mvpLocationPyramid = glGetUniformLocation(basicShader, "mvpMatrix");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpLocationPyramid, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&(T.M));

    GUMatrix4 pyramidModelTransform = GUMatrix4::translationMatrix(-5.75f, 0.0f, 0.0f) * GUMatrix4::scaleMatrix(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f);
    GUMatrix4 mvpPyramid = T * pyramidModelTransform;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpLocationPyramid, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&(mvpPyramid.M));

    // Bind VAO that contains all relevant pyramid VBO buffer and attribute pointer bindings
    glBindVertexArray(pyramidVAO);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pyramidTexture);
    // Draw pyramid
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)0);

    // Unbind pyramid VAO (or bind another VAO)
    glBindVertexArray(0);


    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

I've been trying to fix this for hours now without any luck, as such any support would be massively appreciated!!!

**EDIT: Added in VAO attributes + Shaders**

***VAO Settings***

```
// Per-vertex position vectors
static float pyramidVertices[32] =
{
  //Front
  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   //BtmLeft
  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   //BtmRight
  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   //TopRight
  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   //TopLeft
  //Back
  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   //TopLeft
  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   //TopRight
  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   //BottomRight
  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f    //BottomLeft
};


// Per-vertex colours (RGBA) floating point values
static float pyramidColours[32] =
{
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};

// 5 faces each with 3 vertices (each face forms a triangle)
static unsigned short pyramidVertexIndices[36] =
{
    //Front
    0, 3, 2,
    2, 1, 0,
    //Right
    4, 3, 0,
    0, 7, 4,
    //Back
    4, 7, 6,
    6, 5, 4, 
    //Top
    4, 5, 3,
    3, 5, 2,
    //Left
    2, 5, 1,
    1, 5, 6,
    //Bottom
    6, 7, 0, 
    0, 1, 6
};


static unsigned short pyramidTexCoordArray[24] =
{
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
};
```

***Vertex Shader***

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;

layout (location=0) in vec4 vertexPos;
layout (location=3) in vec2 vertexTexCoord;

out vec2 texCoord;

void main(void) {

    mat4 M;
    M[0] = vec4(1.0);

    ivec2 a = ivec2(1, 2);
    //vec3 b = vec3(2.0, 4.0, 1.0) + a;

    texCoord = vertexTexCoord;
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vertexPos;
}
```

***Fragment Shader***

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D texture;

in vec2 texCoord;

layout (location=0) out vec4 fragColour;

void main(void) {

    vec4 texColor = texture2D(texture, texCoord);
    fragColour = texColor;

}
```

Comment: Without seeing the texture coordinates you use and your shaders we cannot help.

Comment: Could you please provide the mesh data and shader source?

Comment: Sorry I knew I was forgetting something. The data has been added to the bottom with the shaders

Comment: Looks for me as if uv-coordinates are constant over the surface.

Comment: The UV coordinates are mapped wrongly as @BDL points out. UV coordinates have 2 axis' ranging from 0 to 1, and should be mapped in a similar manner to a surface. (quad: {0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f} etc.)

Comment: Yeah I was a bit confused about the coords (my friends textures were working so he let me borrow his code, I was gonna sort the coords out when the texture was working! :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined your data as `unsigned short`:

```
static unsigned short pyramidTexCoordArray[24]
```

But it has to be `float`.

Comment: It has to be? What if using GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT?

Comment: The OP initializes it with floating point data and interprets it as floats, and actually stores negative values, so yeah, it has to be `float`.

Comment: This fixed my problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things strange:

You are generating 3 VBOs for texture coordinates, but are just using one. Unless pyramidTexCoordBuffer is of type GLuint[3] (which I assume it is not due to the &), you are writing out of bounds.

*Edit:* This refers to the `glGenBuffers(3, &pyramidTexCoordBuffer);` line, which allocates 3 buffers and stores them in three consecutive `GLuint` variables starting at `pyramidTexCoordBuffer`. Since `pyramidTexCoordBuffer` is most probably a `GLuint`, `pyramidTexCoordBuffer[1]` and `pyramidTexCoordBuffer[2]` refer to unallocated memory.

The `pyramidTexCoordArray` array is specified as `unsigned short`, but you are writing floats to it. Since it is unsigned, at least the negative numbers will be gone.

Additionally, you tell OpenGL with the

```
glVertexAttribPointer(3, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0);
```

line that the data is of type `GL_FLOAT` (which it is not) and that it has two floats per vertex (but the data has 3 elements per vertex):

Comment: He isn't using 3 VBOs for texture coordinates is he? He is using 3 VBOs, but for different data.

Comment: If I understand VAO/VBO properly, I'm using 1 VBO to store the vertex positions, 1 VBO for the colour, 1 for the TextureCoords. 

But changing unsigned short to float has fixed it the texture is now properly showing so thank you so much! I was also unsure why (or if) I needed the 3 sets of coords (I thought that texture coords were u,v so I removed the third values and it still seems to work. Just gotta work out the correct coords now :) )

Comment: I was refering to this line: `glGenBuffers(3, &pyramidTexCoordBuffer);`, which allocates 3 buffers and stores them in three consecutive `GLuint` variables starting at `pyramidTexCoordBuffer`. Since `pyramidTexCoordBuffer` is most probably a `GLuint`, `pyramidTexCoordBuffer[1]` and `pyramidTexCoordBuffer[2]` refer to unallocated memory. I also added this to the question.

Comment: My eyes seem to have missed that, nvm :3